# How to connect to a Webservice from a Windows Mobile Device 6.0

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-mobile

I would like to create a windows mobile application (6.5) which connect to a webservice via GPRS hosted on my server at home. The webservice was tested successfully using a windows application.

Can someone please guide me what should I do because I have no idea of how to proceed.
Some code will be very appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the service is a standard XML or WCF service, then simply right-click on the "References" node in the project's tree and select "Add Web Reference" just like you would with a desktop project.  This will create the proxy classes for you which you can then use in your application, again just like a desktop application.

[MSDN even has a tutorial for these steps.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446547.aspx)

If you've tried this and are having *specific* problems, feel free to provide more detail and we can help you out.