# Accessing WebService From Windows Mobile

Tags: windows, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

I want to access Web service from windows mobile application and want to process data returned by it. I am not finding any step by step guide to it. I found some articles relevant but they don't clearly mention what setting are required to run in the emulator and what setting are required in order to run on the physical device. Please suggest me best way.
Beginner always need guidance from scratch so there should be some step by step article.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289906/how-to-connect-to-a-webservice-from-a-windows-mobile-device-6-0

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any detailed instructions but I've done heaps of this soft of thing. It's exactly the same as connecting a normal Windows app to a web service. You way want to try this first using a simple WinForms app so you understand the basics of creating a web reference.

The only complication is that your emulator or mobile device will need to be able to connect to the machine running the web service but this should also be pretty easy. Just set up a simple html test page on your PC and ensure you can browse to this using the emulator.