# A lot of data in WP 7 App, how?

Tags: c#, xml, sqlite, quotes, windows-phone-7

I would like to have a lot of data (quotes of famous people, arround 100 k quotes). And I want that users are able to search, sort on category and sort on authors.

Got a big big xml file at the moment, but what is smart to do? How can i get all the quotes in the app? maybe a sql lite database? or just loop the xml when app starts?

Any tips are most welcome!

Kevin

**UPDATE**: Thanks for all the replies and tips, I really appreciate it and I am looking forward to program my App, did make a runkeeper-like app yesterday, now starting the quotes app.

Comment: like 500 mb, what do you suggest? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a SQL CE database (.sdf file)

Great overview here: http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/Windows-Phone-Mango-Local-Database%28SQL-CE%29-Introduction

And here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202860%28v=VS.92%29.aspx

Comment: What will be the size of my app with this? sounds promising but I am affraid with like 80 000 quotes (xml file of 500mb) the database is gonna be very big and the app will be big too? too big maybe?

Comment: Well, 500 MB is not something that you should ever store locally on a small device like a phone unless the user specifically approves of it. Store it on the web server and request a random quote on demand. Read up on doing WCF from WP7.

Comment: Okay thanks! :) but how other quote apps get so many quotes (like 50 k ) in their app and their size is only like 19 MB... they dont use internet connection..

Comment: 50k quotes in 19 MB is about 400 bytes per quote. Your 80k quotes in 500 MB is about 6000 bytes per quote. Maybe you should consider more optimal storage alternatives. Zip-compressed data perhaps? Insert all your quotes into a SQL CE database and see how large the data file gets. Maybe its a viable option.

Comment: =D thanks a lot. I understand I have too much data arround my real data, actually I have more xml code compared to the text of the quotes haha. Well I will try it out in the SQL CE database :)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend storing this data on a webserver somewhere and using some SOAP interface of something like this, to access it. I wouldn't be positively surprised when a downloaded application all of a sudden decides to download a big file of quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Well I hoped that the app would work without the need of internet connection ;) but I am gonna look into this!

Answer (score 0):

There's no SQLite on WP7. There's SQL Server Compact though. Read up on the latter, and also on LINQ. WP7.5 only.

Alternatively, store data on the Web server, and use a service to pull it on demand. In that case, read up on services and SOAP.

Comment: Sounds nice, but same question as below, again thanks for the reply. But how big would my app be? got a xml file of like 500mb.

Comment: The MS Market limit on app size os 10MB IIRC.500MB? Forget on-device storage, go with the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like let the user to enter three character minimum before search from webservice ans user the service result to bind the data.

Check the following links

1. [How to connect to a Webservice from a Windows Mobile Device 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289906/how-to-connect-to-a-webservice-from-a-windows-mobile-device-6-0)
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446547.aspx

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks, well I to create authors and categories pages as well, so that will be a problem with this solution?

Comment: let me know more, we can crack that.

Comment: sorry for my bad english previous post, dont know what happened.. Well I want to have an authors page and categories page, so a list of all authors and categories.

Answer (score 0):

With the fact that you are looking at a 500mb file I think you have a couple of options.

1) Put all of this data in a database on a webserver, then have your phone application use whatever method you like to contact the database to get specific data that is needed. Obviously your UI would have to be optimised to allow a user to sort by the type of quote and / or the person to whom the quote is attributed.

2) If you want this to be done without the use of the webserver you could have a stripped down basic database of quotes in the application itself, to extend this connect to the database and download more data.

This method may be best as it lets you use the database data to say populate a website if you wanted to (make a bit of money from ad revenue / promote your app) and also it means if your users dont have an internet connection they can still get some use from your app.

Without more knowledge of the platform I couldnt say what would happen if you try load a 500mb application but I doubt it would be good, though having such a large file locally is a bad idea for a mobile device. I can see this going two ways.

1) Im out and see your application, I set it downloading, pay it no attention and then later check to find it has downloaded 500mb over my mobile phone data package. This could mean a big bill.

2) I start to download your application, it hasnt finished downloading after 10mins, I delete it and dont bother trying again.